# Wiring gas hob with electric ignition to mains

Tags: electrical, kitchens, oven

We are currently in the process of moving into our newly renovated house. The electrician has completely rewired the house, and the plastering has been done. Only when we went to install the oven and hob did we discover that the electrician hadn't added a socket underneath the worktop for connecting the electronic ignition of our gas hob.

There is a cooker control unit (CCU) for the oven, but no single socket for the 3A plug of the hob. I don't want to drill through the work surface and lose the single socket on the CCU. My question is, can I simply hard wire a surface-mounted single socket to the cooker outlet, and then plug the hob's ignition into that?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) was the only online dictionary that had a reference to a Cooktop, when searching for [hob](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hob).  Though I still had to click the second result to find it.

Comment: It sounds like this house may be in the UK. While the laws of physics governing electricity may be universal, the laws of man vary greatly from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. Make sure any advice works in light of your local electric code.

Comment: Can you convert the single socket into a double socket. Assuming that it is a gas cooktop  from the use of the word electric igniter.

Answer (score 2):

### If it is solely for the use of the electronic ignition then wire it in anywhere you please. The ignition does not use that much power.

**But** if it has a electrocnic cooker then you need a dedicated socket AND dedicated breaker with out anything else running on that ciruit, which is also rated at high amperage and earth leakage.(Usually stoves likes this do not use a plug but have to be hard wired with copper cable into the oven where there are several warning messages)

Comment: But what about overcurrent protection for the hob?